# No puedo generar una tabla LATEX en RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown

que tal. Estoy trabajando con la función feols del paquete fixest para realizar una estimación de un modelo con efectos fijos. En general, el código corre tanto en un script de R como de R Markdown. Sin embargo, al tratar de crear una tabla con la función etable, solo obtengo el código Latex. Mi archivo en rmd luce (con un ejemplo de R) así:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: '2022-07-16'
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---
```

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
{r}
library(fixest)
library(tinytex)

est1 = feols(Ozone ~ i(Month) / Wind + Temp, data = airquality)
est2 = feols(Ozone ~ i(Month, Wind) + Temp | Month, data = airquality)

etable(est1,est2, tex = T)
```

No tengo instalado MikTex, pero si descargué Tinytex usando:

```
install.packages('tinytex')
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

Al correr el código tanto en R como en rmd e incluir tex = T, obtengo sólo código Latex.

De acuerdo a R, estoy usando la última versión. No se si es necesario descargar otro complemento. Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para que me funcionara el código, tuve que incluir el paquete `booktabs` de LaTeX en el YAML

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: '2022-07-16'
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---
```

Por otra parte `library(tinytex)` no es necesario aquí, ya que solo se utiliza para instalar.
Además añadí:
`echo=FALSE`: esconde el código de fuente
`message=FALSE`: esconde los mensajes
`warning=FALSE`: esconde las advertencias
`results='asis'`: tratara lo que entrega el segmento como código latex

```
{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(fixest)

est1 = feols(Ozone ~ i(Month) / Wind + Temp, data = airquality)
est2 = feols(Ozone ~ i(Month, Wind) + Temp | Month, data = airquality)

etable(est1,est2, tex = T)
```

Espero que esto solucione tu problema.